# Numbers game C++

Tags: c++, numbers

I have a program that stores current a low numbers. The Object is to Store the low number every time time a new number is presented. so say I start the function the first number will equal the low number. but the trouble im having it once the function is called again it starts over and low is erased. Is there a way I can keep the function value once the function is called again? or does anyone know a better way of doing this while keeping function in a class?

Thanks

```
double a;

class rff{ 

public:
    void FGH()
    {
        double  b=0;

        cout<< "pick a number"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        b=a;
        cout << "yournum";
        cout << "LAST num:" << a<< endl;
        cout << "Low num:" << b << endl;

        cout <<"'pick another number"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        if (a < b)
        {
            b = a;
        }
        cout << "yournum";
        cout << "LAST num:" <<a<< endl;
        cout << "Low num:" << b<< endl;
        cin.get();
    }

};
```

and source CPP

```
int main(){
    rff ws;
    ws.FGH();
    ws.FGH();
    ws.FGH();

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do summat about the indentation

Comment: it was a mistake....but i guess programmers as yourselfs never make mistakes XD

Comment: I usually call it breathing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many mistakes in your code. Here I suggest something probably better (not tested, so you will maybe need to adapt it).

```
class MinimalChecker {

private:
    double minValue;

public:
    void MinimalChecker() {
        minValue = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    }

    void check()
    {
        double userInput = 0;

        cout << "Pick a number" << endl;
        cin  >> userInput;
        if (userInput < minValue)
        {
            minValue = userInput;
        }
        cout << "Number typed:" << userInput << endl;
        cout << "Lower number:" << minValue << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
};
```

Changes:

1. Better class/method names, easier to understand
2. No more global variable. Only a class member which store the minimal value starting when user has entered a number for t-he first time. It is initialized in the constructor with max value allowed by double type in c++.
3. Number is asked to user only one time. If you don't do that, each time you run your old FGH() function, the lower number is overriden without condition.